# non-ASCII characters are interpreted as bytes when written to a .csv file

Tags: python, csv, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

When there is a youtube title that has non-ASCII characters ( in my case its greek letters). This is what is being shown on the .csv file after I ran the program.If I hadnt used `utf-8` it doesnt write any youtube titles, its just a blank csv file. In this example that I use `utf-8` it shows the non-ASCII characters (greek letters) as bytes.
[image: CSV]

```
import os
import json
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from datetime import date
import csv


today = date.today()

# Set up the API client
api_key = 'API KEY'
youtube = build("youtube", "v3", developerKey='API KEY')

# Get the top 10 trending videos
request = youtube.videos().list(
    part="snippet", 
    chart="mostPopular",
    regionCode="GR",
    maxResults=10
)
response = request.execute()

# Write the results to a .csv file
try:
    with open("trending.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(["TOP 10 TRENDING YOUTUBE VIDEOS " + str(today)])
        for video in response["items"]:
            writer.writerow([video["snippet"]["title"].encode("utf-8")]) 
except PermissionError:
    print("Permission Error: Your excel file is probably open at the moment. Please close the excel file and try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing `.encode("utf-8")` solves the problem on my end.

Comment: Sorry it was my bad try now the country code should be GR not US. GR as in Greece. Greek letters = non-ASCII characters

Comment: `utf-8-sig` fixed the problem. Thanks though